# Pass modules down - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, import

I have a structure like this:

```
-controllers
 -matches
  -index.js
  -create.js
  -get.js
```

In index I export the other modules like this:

```
const get = require("./get");
const create = require("./create");

module.exports = {
  get,
  create,
}
```

Get example:

```
const MatchModel = require("../../models/Match");

const get = async (req, res, next) => {
  let matches = await MatchModel.find();
  console.log(matches);
};

module.exports = get;
```

Now since get and create share the same module (MatchModel) is there a way to pass it down instead of importing it in every single file?

What I want to do is something like this:
Index:

```
const MatchModel = require("../../models/Match");
const get = require("./get");
const create = require("./create");

module.exports = {
  get,
  create,
}
```

Get example:

```
const get = async (req, res, next) => {
  let matches = await MatchModel.find();
  console.log(matches);
};

module.exports = get;
```

I am using mongoose for the schema.

Comment: you can do something like this, but I don't think in the manner you are attempting. I recommend you (re) read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Aggregating_modules

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js or app.js, the script file where the express app is being exported add

```
global_get = require("../get"); // with the path according to your structure
```

without the identifiers

> Identifiers like **const**, **let** or **var**.

Now you can basically call this module/function anywhere in your nodejs app like:

```
let result = await global.global_get();
```

If you have series of exported function then :

```
let result = await global.global_get.some_function();
```

> Here, **global** or **GLOBAL** (depreciated) identifies global variable throughout the nodejs App.
>
> **However, I would recommend that you import / require the modules wherever it is necessary**